# Тестирование Html + Javascript (Ajax)

Tags: ajax, html, тестирование, javascript

Осваиваю сабж + необходимо этот самый сабж тестировать. Выбрал пока для этих целей HtmlUnit. Для начала задача скачать страницу, дождаться выполнения всех скриптов и вывести содержимое страницы. На простых скриптах все работает, на скриптах чуть сложнее уже не соображу как задействовать HtmlUnit. Первое что пришло в голову, проверить сие чудо на ключевиках яндекса, и не работает. Подскажите, плиз, куда копать :(

Код:

```
public class TestJava {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    // TODO code application logic here

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_7);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://wordstat.yandex.ru");

    HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);
    final HtmlInput keyword = form.getInputByName("text");
    keyword.setValueAttribute("HtmlUnit");
    final DomNodeList<HtmlElement> inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");

    HtmlElement btnSubmit = null;
    for (int n=0; n<inputs.getLength(); ++n)
    {
        final HtmlElement temp = inputs.get(n);
        final String type = temp.getAttribute("type");
        if (type.equals("submit"))
        {
            btnSubmit = temp;
            break;
        }

    };
    if (null != btnSubmit)
    {
        final HtmlPage clickPage = btnSubmit.click();
        System.out.println(clickPage.asXml());
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Ошибка поиска информации");

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

}

Comment: Это, мягко говоря, не самая лучшая идея -- использовать Java для изучения и тестирования html/javascript.  


Comment: а что можете предложить аналогичное HtmlUnit, но не на Java? а, например, на C/C++. Или как еще автоматом протестировать написанные формы/страницы/скрипты?

Comment: а какую цель вы ставите перед автоматическим тестированием?

Comment: грубо если: есть страничка html + js, тесты проходят по этой страничке с разными исходными данными, получают по этим данным отработанный js и на выходе выдают вердикт, соответствуют ли сгенерированные js данные ожидаемым или в логике где-то закралась ошибка. Ну, собссно, стандартное предназначение тестов